# When using Fenians' benefit, do they also add their bomb value?

Tags: a-study-in-emerald

In the second edition of A Study in Emerald, Fenians have a one-use benefit that allows you to have agents count as two Bomb points instead of one. They also have a Bomb point on them.

The rules for assassination say:

> Each card that you play that has symbols on is worth Bomb points equal to the number of such symbols on the card.

Since you are playing the Fenians card to use their benefit at this time, does it also add its own Bomb point, or do cards played for Bomb points have to be played exclusively as such?

Comment: Could you please add a tag wiki to [a-study-in-emerald]? That will prevent it from getting auto-purged in about 6 months.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## No.

Page 6 of the English rulebook states under the sub-heading "A Short Interlude About Cards" that,

> In all circumstances a card can only ever be played for one type of symbol on it or
>   the text effect described in the text box

When played for their ability, Fenians double all bomb points of cards you played to gain bomb points.  If you had two Fenians cards, you could play one for bombs and one as a doubler.

Hope this helps!